# SWF never finishes loading over SSL in IE

Tags: ssl, https, websphere, flash

I have a flex application which was originally deployed on Tomcat running on windows.  It worked fine over both http and https in all browsers.

Recently, I switched over to websphere community edition on linux, and the application works fine, except in IE over https.  When access the application, the swf never finishes loading.  I just see the progress bar, stuck at 1/4 completion, and a white background.

I have researched similar issues on stackoverflow, and tried all suggestions but still it does not work:

I tried turning off caching at the top of my jsp where I embed the SWF:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store,max-age=0,must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I am wondering if websphere ce is putting something in the response header which is preventing my swf from loading over https, as it worked fine in standalone tomcat over https.

I do not see anything suspicious in logs, however, using Fiddler, I noticed the last thing it is doing is trying to download two cross domain files over http from fpdownload.adobe.com:

/pub/swz/crossdomain.xml 
and 
/crossdomain.xml

Then normally several BlazeDS calls are made.  This never happens.

Comment: Anything in the log files? I mean SystemOut.log, SystemErr.log, http_access.log, http_error.log

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove all cache-control headers.
Check http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234067 for more information in this regard.